# How do I make a custom prefix setter with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a custom prefix setter with quick.db. I found out is uses sqlite which heroku obviously can't support due to it being a file in your bots and when you update it, it would reset it to the local hosts file. Which would reset it. So I wanna change from quick.db to mongodb. This is my prefix that is set.

```js
const prefix = bot.db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
  ? bot.db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
  : config.prefix;
```

So how would I make it to mongodbs so it fetches it from mongodb and not quick.db. I also need todo the same for my setprefix command.

Comment: What should I share?

Comment: Did you find solution? Are you looking for MongoDb equivalence of you code?

Comment: I never did. I'm looking to change the const prefix to mongodb instead of quick.db.